# Ansible Git clone escape special charecter

Tags: git, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to clone a git repo using git module. My below code perfectly works most of the time but fails when a password contains '#' character with it (My doubt it might fail with other charecter as well).

Please help me to find a way to escape special charecter in password.

```
---
host: 127.0.0.1
become: true
become_user: root

tasks:
  - name: clone git repo.
    git:
      repo: "{{userName}}:{{password | urlencode}}@x.x.x.x/scm/test.git"
      dest: /tmp/test
      version: master
      force: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the password within single quotes i.e

`'{{ password }}'`

Also if SSH cloning is an option my suggestion would be to switch to SSH